# Is there the way to reanalyze only current project in Google Dart Editor?

Tags: ide, dart, editor, usability, dart-editor

By the command `Reanalyze sources` the Google Dart Editor always reanalyzes all opened projects for the editing but not only the current active project.
Reanalyzing all the opened project can take a long time, especially if of open projects, there are about a dozen.

Is there the way to reanalyze only current active project in Google Dart Editor?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can exclude projects and folders with `Don't analyze` from the context menu.